# Path length requirement for diffraction problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, visible-light, diffraction, crystals

The following question has been asked in a problem sheet I have been asked to answer:
[image]

"The above diagram relates to the path lengths of radiation, with an angle of incidence,
θ, reflecting off consecutive planes of a crystal, spaced by a distance $d$. Why must the relation, $2(l'-l) = nλ$, be satisfied in order to see diffracted radiation?"

If I am honest, I don't really know where to begin. I could attempt all kinds of trigonometry but I think my problem lies in the fact that fact that I think I must not know a certain condition for diffraction to occur. I know $d$ should, ideally, be equal to the wavelength but I don't think this is the correct condition given that the expression if equal to $n\lambda$ rather than $\lambda$ alone. Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: For constructive interference you need the optical path difference to be *some whole number* of wavelengths, roughly speaking so that the peaks become realigned after travelling the two different paths

Comment: Thanks. However, what's the relation between diffraction and constructive interference in this case?

Comment: Constructive interference is the mechanism that gives you non-zero intensity. Diffraction is the name for this interferometric phenomenon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps part of the problem is that the statement $2 ( l - l') = n \lambda$ is not correct in general. It applies to the specific situation where both the incident wavefront and the refracted wavefront accumulates a path difference of $l - l'$ between each layer of your crystal. That is true if the diffraction causes a reflection back in the same direction where the incident wave came from, or else a reflection where the angle of reflection is equal to the angle of incidence.

If that condition is true, the equation follows from the requirement that you are looking for constructive interference: Over the (difference in) propagation length for the separate paths, you want the wave to repeat. Since its spatial period is the wavelength $\lambda$, that means you want an integer multiple of it ($n \lambda$) equal to this distance.

Comment: Where does the factor of two come from?

Comment: Forth and back. In general, along different paths (due to possibly different angles), but the author of the question appears to assume those are the same distance.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I completely understand. What do you mean forth and back?

Comment: After the waves have reached a deeper layer (gone forth), how to they return (go back) to the top layer?